# MS git provider in Visual Studio: where do I set push target?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Using Microsoft git provider in Visual Studio. In Synchronisation tab there was a setting for the remote repo. Entered a wrong name, now get an error message

*"Error encountered while publishing branch to the remote repository: Could not find repository from ..."*

I understand the error, but since a while I cannot find anywhere a setting where I can adjust the remote repo?

**Where do I set the push target?**

(Tried normal git tools, but there was no setting of the wrong repo.
Searched all files for thename of the wrong repo, nothing found.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be done from team explorer (in vs2015): team-explorer - settings
On the bottom (under Diff & Merge tools) there is a 'Remotes' item where you can add, delete or change the push target.

Answer (score 2):

The remote name shouldn't be in a regular file, but in the `.git/config` file of your repo.
You can change it with:

```
git remote set-url origin /right/url/of/repo
```

Check also the configuration for the branches:

```
git branch -avvv
```

One of them might be set up to push to the remote "`E:/xxx/yyy`" instead of "`origin`", which would explain the error message.

Comment: bingo, looks good! thx a lot for that hint, was stuck. mark it later